# System.NotSupportedException ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to verify data in my controller. The data which I m passing copied from another field in the same view. Data conditions are satisfied, the data is passing, but after the data is passed, I am having an error System.NotSupportedException which I am unable trace either.

View [I am hiding couple of fields and copying the data from another field into these fields becuas I am unable to verify TaxID data with SSN]:

```
<body>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TAxIDType, Model.TAxIDType, new { id = "taxid" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TAxIDType)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TaxID, new { id="taxidinput", @class = "feintextbox", maxlength = 9, @placeholder = "xxxxxxxxx" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TaxID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FEIN, new { id="feinfield", @class = "feintextbox", maxlength = 10, @placeholder = "xxxxxxxxx" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FEIN)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SSN, new { id="ssnfield", @class = "ssntextbox", maxlength = 10, @placeholder = "xxxxxxxxx" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SSN)
</body>
<script>
   $(function () {
   $('#feinfield').hide();
   });
   $(function () {
   $('#ssnfield').hide();
   });
   $("#taxidinput").keypress(function () {
   $("#ssnfield").val($(this).val());
   });
   $("#taxidinput").keypress(function () {
   $("#feinfield").val($(this).val());
   });
</script>
```

Controller [I am showing only one condition(SSN verification)]:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CorporationRegistrationPg1(Testing CorporationRegistration, string EmailID, int SSN, int FEIN, string TAxIDType)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         using (SUPRTestingDBEntities2 db = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2())
         {
if (TAxIDType == "SSN")
                    {
                        var obj = db.SUPRTesting.Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(CorporationRegistration.EmailID) && a.SSN.Equals(CorporationRegistration.SSN)).FirstOrDefault();
//This is where I am getting the error
//System.NotSupportedException
//The specified type member 'FEIN' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
//Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            if (obj.Active == 0 && obj.Submit == 0)
                            {
                                Session["LoginID"] = obj.LoginID.ToString();
                                Session["EmailAddress"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                                return RedirectToAction("CorporationRegistrationPg2");
                            } else
                            {
                                var Testing = new Testing();
                                return View(Testing);
                            }}
                        else if (obj == null)
                        {
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
```

I have declared all the fields in the controller. Yet, I am getting the error in my controller.

Model:

```
 public partial class Testing
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public int TaxID { get; set; }
        public int SSN { get; set; }
        public int FEIN { get; set; }
        public int Active { get; set; }
        public int Submit { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> TAxIDType = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Select here", Value="default"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="SSN", Value="SSN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="FEIN", Value="FEIN"}
        };
}
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: I don't see FEIN in the query. So, are you sure you are seeing error exactly at the line mentioned  `db.SUPRTesting.Where...`? Please refer my comments and update the post.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with the the line mentioned. FEIN logic is hidden in here because both SSN and FEIN carry the same logic. Also, I believe the issue is with the way I am copying data from one TextBox to another in the view.

Comment: please post the complete statement which includes FEIN and also let us know parameter values to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Constants/Enums `CorporationRegistration.EmailID` and `CorporationRegistration.SSN` are causing the `NotSupported` Exception when retrieving the data back via Entity Framework.

Try and change them to integers or strings (Depending on their underlying data type), for example:

```
int corpRegistrationEmailId = (int) CorporationRegistration.EmailID;
int corpRegistrationSSN = (int) CorporationRegistration.SSN;
```

Or strings:

```
string corpRegistrationEmailId = CorporationRegistration.EmailID.ToString();
string corpRegistrationSSN = CorporationRegistration.SSN.ToString();
```

And then reference the variables directly in the `.Where` clause.

```
var obj = db.SUPRTesting
          .Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(corpRegistrationEmailId) &&
          a.SSN.Equals(corpRegistrationSSN)).FirstOrDefault();
```

From your update (Including the Testing Model).  You may want to remove the `List<SelectListItem>` property for TaxIDType, Entity Framework may have issues converting this type to an underlying SQL type, hence the NotSupported exception.

As a best practice, you may want to refactor your Controller and move the database logic into an appropriate tier (Such as a DAL / Service layer) rather than performing database operations directly at the Controller level.

As an additional note, you could also focus on indentation/code style and remove magic strings/magic numbers from the code base which would make your code easier to read and help with maintainability.

Comment: I am still having the issue. Unable to do conversion to int. Tried conversion to string, issue still persists.

Comment: @Harsha - See my edit.  I think it is the TaxIDType that is causing the issue as Entity Framework will not be able to map this correctly.

Comment: Darren, in my View, I was passing <TextBoxFor>TaxID to SSN textbox using jquery and in the post action trying to match this copied data. The problem is with the copying of data. When I tried to validate TaxID directly instead of SSN, I worked fine and redirected me to next page.